# What can I do to solve telegram.ext.JobQueue errors in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, python-telegram-bot

I intended to use **telegram.ext.JobQueue** in my code to run **news()** function every **30 seconds**. This function sends a **document** for me in telegram. Here is my code:

```
def start(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    update.message.reply_text(
        "Hello, Welcome to my Bot. Please write /help to see the commands available.")
    context.job_queue.run_repeating(news, interval=30, first=10, context=update.message.chat_id)

def news(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):

    s = io.StringIO()
    csv.writer(s).writerows(newlist)
    s.seek(0)
    buf = io.BytesIO()
    buf.write(s.getvalue().encode())
    buf.seek(0)
    buf.name = f'items.csv'
    context.bot.send_document(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, document=buf)
```

The following line makes the error:

```
context.job_queue.run_repeating(news, interval=30, first=10, context=update.message.chat_id)
```

I got this error when I click /start in the telegram bot:

```
No error handlers are registered, logging exception.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/arman/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/telegram/ext/dispatcher.py", line 555, in process_update
    handler.handle_update(update, self, check, context)
  File "/Users/arman/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/telegram/ext/handler.py", line 198, in handle_update
    return self.callback(update, context)
  File "/Users/arman/Downloads/test3.py", line 23, in start
    context.job_queue.run_repeating(news, interval=10, first=10, context=update.message.chat_id)
  File "/Users/arman/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/telegram/ext/jobqueue.py", line 293, in run_repeating
    j = self.scheduler.add_job(
  File "/Users/arman/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apscheduler/schedulers/base.py", line 434, in add_job
    job = Job(self, **job_kwargs)
  File "/Users/arman/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apscheduler/job.py", line 49, in __init__
    self._modify(id=id or uuid4().hex, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/arman/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apscheduler/job.py", line 180, in _modify
    check_callable_args(func, args, kwargs)
  File "/Users/arman/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apscheduler/util.py", line 401, in check_callable_args
    raise ValueError('The following arguments have not been supplied: %s' %
ValueError: The following arguments have not been supplied: context
```

**What can I do to solve this problem?**

Answer (score 0):

As detailed in the [tutorial](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/v13.x-wiki/wiki/Extensions-%E2%80%93-JobQueue), the [example](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/tree/v13.x/examples#timerbotpy) and the [documentation](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/stable/telegram.ext.jobqueue.html#telegram.ext.JobQueue.run_repeating), job callbacks take exactly one argument of type `CallbackContext` - not two.

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`.